# Is there a way to get recommendations with facebook query language?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-recommendations

I need to embed the facebook recommendations into my web control. How can i query them from facebook? Is there any method for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the graph doesn't support it as far as the documentation shows. But you might be able to scrape the information from a url.  Hint, the recommendations plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/) has an iframe option ;)